# How fast do ions move in body when they go in and out of the cell membrane?

Tags: cell-biology, membrane

Do we have any measurement tools to measure the speed of ions moving in a human body, specifically going in and out of the cell membrane? Do we have any tools to know where an ion is at a specific time?

Comment: Why do you want to know? Might https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/401068 apply to your question? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion

Comment: We do - check out [patch-clamping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_clamp)